# Android Rotation Redirects to root URL for webview

Tags: android, laravel, vue.js, webview, rotation

I have a web application that is built in Laravel and Vue.js. I have used the application in android as WebView. The problem occurs when I rotate my android device. After rotating the application, it redirects to the root URL from any page but it should stay on the same page. Is it possible to solve it from the web application site? If not, then how can I solve this from Android application.

This is not happening in iOS and browser. The problem is occurring only in Android application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **configChanges**

> Please try below approach

in your manifest xml file,
 add below code in your `activity` tag, in which you are showing webview.

```
<activity
    android:name=".youractivityname"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"/>
```

> For more info please refer this [Handle configuration changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes)

Answer (score 1):

That is because onCreate() is being called again iclude below code in manifest of app

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```